# Deteriorating Cactus

Tags: cactus

My cactus is showing signs which might be detrimental to its health.
[This is an image of the cactus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5uil.jpg)

1. The base of the cactus has a white coloration but is still firm( I don't think its a sign of rot)
2. The pad has a light green coloration compared to the other healthy cactus.[The comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz8FD.jpg)
3. The cactus has not shown any growth since it was propagated 2 months ago.

Can someone give suggestions on how to deal with this situation
(the scar on the big cactus pad was present before proagation)
The cactus does have a well established root system and stands firm in the pot)

Comment: Another point to note that due to my lack of knowledge about cactus propagation, I had burried the cactus pad upto the point of white colouration

Comment: Where in the world are you? Opuntias generally put new pads on in the spring and the pads get bigger throughout the year. It looks well hydrated, but it doesn't look like it's getting enough sun. You also need to fertilize during the spring/summer.